# Add something about support to the title placeholder

Tags: feature-request, title

Before you ask empty fields contain placeholders. I’m slightly confused why does title not contain something about support request?

> [image: no support]

Should we add “support request”-like text to the title placeholder?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to change it other than "it feels odd that's it's missing"? Is there someone that actually got confused because it wasn't explicitly mentioned there? I'm not a fan of making the placeholder even longer just to include a couple more words that don't have any actual benefit.